# AsyncTask and variables

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I write Android application with service and AsynTaskLoader, but it doen't work correctly because one variable (I store it in preferences) change value after onPostExetute will be completed(Loger show this), can I change it or create a delay?

My function in Service:

```
private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
    LocalLog.appendLog("Autobus66Service display logging info");
    LocalLog.appendLog("Autobus66Service isLoaderRunning = "
        + MainActivity.isLoaderRunning);
    if(MainActivity.isLoaderRunning==false){
        new LoaderInBackground(getApplicationContext(),
            Autobus66Service.this).execute((Void[]) null);
    }
    Preferences prefs = new Preferences(this);
    boolean doActivityLoading = prefs.doActivityLoading();
    LocalLog.appendLog("Autobus66Service doActivityLoading = "
        + doActivityLoading);
    if (doActivityLoading) {
        isRunning = MainActivity.isActive;
        closeAnotherActivities();
        LocalLog.appendLog("Autobus66Service isRunning = " + isRunning);
        Log.d("Autobus66Service isMainActivityRunning"
            + isRunning,MainActivity.TAG6);
        if (isRunning) {
            MainActivity.isCallFromAnotherActivity = true;
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        } else {
            startActvityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startActvityIntent);
        }
        Autobus66WakeLock.lockOn(this);
    }
}
```

it uses variable doActivityLoading but in this example unforchunately it uses old value not new from LoaderInBackground. Can you say how to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do something after the onPostExecute, you should use an interface in your AsyncTask.

```
interface ASyncResponse {
    public void onDone(boolean response);
}
```

then, define your AsyncTask and create a constructor that has the response object

```
public static class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    ASyncResponse response;

    //  constructor
    public SomeTask(ASyncResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do some BG work
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // send back the response once background process is done
        response.onDone(result);
    }
}
```

to use it, simply call

```
    SomeTask  someTask = new SomeTask(new ASyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onDone(boolean response) {
            // once AsyncTask is done, do your stuff
        }
    });
    someTask.execute();
```